# Can I run Linux on the HP Mini from Verizon Wireless, with a built-in 3G modem, and connect using the built in modem?

Tags: linux, connection, netbook

Recently I purchases the HP Mini from Verizon Wireless. It runs on the Intel Atom processor and came with Windows 7 Starter Edition, which is quite possibly the worst and most restrictive OS I have ever used. I plan on installing CRUX, after doing a little research on minimal, free, Linux operating systems, as I am working on web programming using Python, among other things.

My only worry is that, because my HP Mini uses a built in wireless card (and I have no Wi-Fi connection, only a 3G connection) that has a "mobile access" connection to Verizon wireless, I am not sure if after installing CRUX that I would still be able to connect using this option. I have never used Linux before, and am hoping this will work. Can I connect to VZW 3G with Linux, using an internal mobile access card...